# C++ const "and the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member

Tags: c++, constants, strcmp

I'm new to C++ programming and in my OPP class we were requested to create a phone book.

Now, in the lecture the Professor said something about that if you want to make sure that your variable that is being injected to a method doesn't get changed you must put const on it.

here is my code so far.

```
private:
 static int phoneCount;
 char* name;
 char* family;
 int phone;
 Phone* nextPhone;

public:
    int compare(const Phone&other) const;
    const char* getFamily();
    const char* getName();
```

and in Phone.cpp

```
int Phone::compare(const Phone & other) const
{
 int result = 0;
 result = strcmp(this->family, other.getFamily());
 if (result == 0) {
    result = strcmp(this->name, other.getName);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I keep getting "the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member"
 when I try to call to strcmp inside my compare function.
I know that I can just remove the const in the function declaration and it will go away, but I still doesn't understand why it's showing in the first place.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, use `std::string`, and don't mix defining a collection of `Phone`s with defining `Phone`

Comment: @Caleth Intrusive lists are not necessarily an antipattern (in fact they used to be extraordinarily common) though I would tend to agree that for modern production C++ it's a bit ew

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `const` qualifier for getters `const char* getFamily() const;`. This way these getters can be invoked on objects of type `const Phone &` that you pass into function.

Also `other.getName` should be `other.getName()`.

Comment: Thank you, that so obvious in retrospective

Answer (score 2):

Your signature

```
int Phone::compare(const Phone & other) const
```

means inside that function you need to ensure you don't change the `Phone` instance.

At the moment, your function calls `const char* getFamily()` (and `getName`, which you've missed the `()` call from). Neither of these functions are `const`, hence the error.

If you mark these as const too, it will be ok.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers that correctly suggest `const` qualifying your getters, you can access the data members of `other` directly, avoiding those calls.

```
int Phone::compare(const Phone & other) const
{
 int result = strcmp(family, other.family);
 if (result == 0) {
    result = strcmp(name, other.name);
 }
 return result;
}
```